# client side sorting in ngx-datatable angular

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

client side sorting works if we specify columns as shown below.

View page

```
<ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns"> </ngx-datatable>
```

ts page

```
columns = [{ prop: 'name' }, { name: 'Gender' }, { name: 'Company' }];
```

but if we remove the column definiton from ts page and then specify them in view page as

```
<ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="rows">
    <ngx-datatable-column>
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
        <span>name</span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row.name }}
      </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column>
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <span>Gender</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      {{row.Gender}}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
<ngx-datatable-column>
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
    <span>Company</span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    {{row.Company}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
```

sorting fails.
any idea why this happens.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems an issue with your HTML template. This is work for me without columns definition.

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows">

  <ngx-datatable-column name="name">
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      {{row.name}}
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>

  <ngx-datatable-column name="company">
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      {{row.company}}
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>

</ngx-datatable>
```

also, we can use these ways to sort.

```
<ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="rows" [sorts]="[{prop: 'name', dir: 'desc'}]">
```

,

```
<ngx-datatable-column [sortable]="true" name="name">
```

or

```
  columns = [
    { name: 'company', sortable: true },
    { name: 'name', sortable: false }
  ];
```

Comment: The above solution forces the model for row to have exactly the same attributes as the columns. If you are deriving new columns in the template (and accessing data via row) the sort will not work. Is there a way to make sort work without defining the name (or prop) of a column ?

Comment: You can use `prop` such as`<ngx-datatable-column [prop]="'rule.name'" >` to drill down in the row model for more deeply nested attributes, so your row model does not have to be flat and it can contain objects.  But it does not seem to  be able to drill down to array items.   This information might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to disable ngx-datatable sort and use only client sorting, my code:

```
<ngx-datatable
            ...
            [externalSorting] = "true"
            (sort)="onPageSorted($event)">
 </ngx-datatable>

onPageSorted($event) {
    let _sort = $event.sorts[0];
    this.filter.orderByColumnNameDESC = _sort.dir == 'desc' && _sort.prop == 'ColumnName';
    this.filter.orderByColumnNameASC = _sort.dir == 'asc' && _sort.prop == 'ColumnName';


    event.stopPropagation(); - stop auto table sort to use only from server
    event.preventDefault();
    this.performFilter(); - here your client request with this.filter params
}
```